# Using a for loop with a try except block but still gives me an error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-except, nosuchelementexception

I am new and trying to create a bot project using python and selenium.
In this section of my bot, I am trying to create a for loop such that the program refreshes the page a few times (using the search and back button), before moving on with the rest of the while loop which I have excluded as it is not as relevant to the error im getting.

So, what im trying to do is to find a slot to book. If a slot is found, the back button we become obsolete and there wont be such an element anymore in the webpage. So, I made use of this functionality to get out of the refreshing loop, and instead move on to the except block which would hopefully get me out of both loops (the for loop and while loop). However, I think that I still am unable to get out of the for loop as I see this error popping up, even though I have attempted to handle the NoSuchElementException error.

```
no_slot = True
while no_slot == 1:
    for i in range(60):
        search_button = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "btnSearch")
        search_button.click()
        try:
            noslot_back_button = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="btnBack"]')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            no_slot = False
            break
        else:
            noslot_back_button.click()
```

This is the error I received:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jonathan/PycharmProjects/Riddle/BBDC_fullauto.py", line 81, in <module>
    noslot_back_button = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="btnBack"]')
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1238, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name="btnBack"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00CC3AB3+2505395]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C5AE41+2076225]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B62498+1057944]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B8CB74+1231732]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BB6D92+1404306]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA5A2A+1333802]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BB5168+1397096]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA58BB+1333435]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B823E4+1188836]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B8323F+1192511]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E4CB36+1554566]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00EF4A0C+2242396]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D50E0B+523099]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D4FEB0+519168]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C602FD+2097917]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C64388+2114440]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C644C2+2114754]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C6E041+2154561]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7592FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x774E7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x774E7A6E+238]
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\PyCharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\PyCharm\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Jonathan/PycharmProjects/Riddle/BBDC_fullauto.py", line 89, in <module>
    slot_submit_button.click()
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 693, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\venvs\automation\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="button" name="" value="Submit" class="btn" onclick="postBooking(this.form, 'b-TPDSBookingConfirm.asp?limit=TPDS', '', 'Please select a slot to book.')" onmouseover="blueBtnOver(this)" onmouseout="blueBtnOut(this)"> is not clickable at point (118, 330). Other element would receive the click: <td align="right" class="bluetxtbold">...</td>
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00CC3AB3+2505395]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C5AE41+2076225]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B62498+1057944]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B92C09+1256457]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B90F48+1249096]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B8ED0D+1240333]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B8DB68+1235816]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B83857+1194071]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA59F3+1333747]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B83676+1193590]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA5ADA+1333978]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BB5168+1397096]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA58BB+1333435]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B823E4+1188836]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B8323F+1192511]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E4CB36+1554566]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00EF4A0C+2242396]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D50E0B+523099]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D4FEB0+519168]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C602FD+2097917]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C64388+2114440]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C644C2+2114754]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C6E041+2154561]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7592FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x774E7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x774E7A6E+238]
python-BaseException
```

Comment: Remember that Chrome is running in a completely separate process.  It is not part of Python.  When it gets an exception, it's doing its own exception processing.

Comment: Also there seems to be an overlapping element given by selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="button" name="" value="Submit" class="btn" onclick="postBooking(this.form, 'b-TPDSBookingConfirm.asp?limit=TPDS', '', 'Please select a slot to book.')" onmouseover="blueBtnOver(this)" onmouseout="blueBtnOut(this)"> is not clickable at point (118, 330). Other element would receive the click: <td align="right" class="bluetxtbold">...</td> . You can avoid this error by  a click on the element through driver.execute_script.

Comment: Hi @ArundeepChohan, let me explain my interpretation of the error received. So during the try except block that is moved onto the except block due to the back button no longer being clickable, another error has happened within the except block, resulting in this overlapping error? Also, could you elaborate what the driver.execute_script will help me in my case? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to import the exception?

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: Hi I did import the exception